# Can the Playhead in Animation Editors be Moved with Script?

Tags: animation, scripting, interface

Ideally, what I would like to see is a feature that lets me float the cursor over an animation editor window, such as the *Dope Sheet*, and then immediately press a sequence of number keys to instantly move the playhead to whatever frame corresponds to the number entered. I do not believe having this option would lead to any input conflicts, since normally, you would begin with keys other than numbers to initiate various functions within these editors, such as beginning with "g" to grab a keyframe, followed by a letter defining an axis, and then finally a number defining a destination frame. By starting with a number, instead of finishing with one, you would be telling Blender that you simply want to move the playhead by itself. I think this would be really handy.

Could this be done through scripting? Or is the playhead positioning so ingrained in the Blender API that script can't target it?

Comment: Script can definitely target it, but I'm not sure how you'd set up the shortcuts via scripting. You can access the current frame using bpy.context.scene.frame_current. You can set it using bpy.context.scene.frame_set(desired_frame_here).